# elasticsearch kibana to Jira service management ssl error

Tags: elasticsearch, devops, jira

I am able to establish connection between elastic search kibana and jira service management(jirasm) cloud  but getting ssl error for connection between elastic search kibana and jira service managment(jirasm) data center version.

```
Error:
Action][Jira]: Unable to get capabilities. Error: write EPROTO 140447345760192:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332: . Reason: unknown: errorResponse was null
```

I am planning to create the incident in jirasm. Can advise any ssl configuration required.

Comment: Do you have custom self-signed SSL certificate on Jira DC? If so, then you need to import the root CA certificate to ESK store or disable SSL certificate verification or communicate over http instead of https.

Comment: Hi @CraZ, If we disable the ssl certificate verification then will impact security of other nodes. I am using JIRA Service management DC, seems there is no option for self signed certificate. Is there any documentation to validate the two way communication between elastic search and Jira Service management Data center version.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/alert-action-settings-kb.html#action-settings

set

```
xpack.actions.ssl.verificationMode: none
```

in `kibana.yml`